# Export.image.toDrive in TIFF format in GEE takes forever

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I'm working with high resolution water data (30 m, Globas Surface Water Explorer). I need to ensure that all calculations are done in a certain projection (EPSG:4326) and after all calculations I want to extract to my Drive results that are aggregated to 1km, ~1.8 km and 5.5 km.
I can see results, and extraction is working without errors but it's been already more than 10 days and it keeps running. I have space in my GoogleDrive.
I tried following extraction:

```
var template_Global_01km = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/CLM/CLM_LST_MOD11A2-DAYNIGHT_M/v01").select('jan'); 
var globe_export = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-179.9999999999999999, -90, 180, 90], 'EPSG:4326', false); 
var dimensions_Global_01km = '43200x21600'; 
var maxPixels_numberD = 1e10; // max pixels for region reduction and download
var fileFormat_name = 'GeoTIFF'; // file format
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: lsm_Global_01km,
  description: 'lsm_Global_01km',
  folder: folder_name,
  dimensions: dimensions_Global_01km,
  region: globe_export,
  crs: template_Global_01km.projection().crs().getInfo(),
  maxPixels: maxPixels_numberD,
  skipEmptyTiles: false,
  fileFormat: fileFormat_name
});
```

I also tried to exract to Asset as thought it would be faster but it's the same - no errors and runs forever.
Script link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmargaritachoulga%2FSTATIC_MAPS%3AStaticFields_water
Process Id 1: 66RXL5VFRB5O6UQF3JGE7X5G
Process Id 2: K65C7CW3QOYNSR5XGX6VC67U

Comment: Well, calculating and exporting 1km data for the entire earth is bound to take a while. A week still seems a bit excessive to see no results. Have you already tried refreshing your page? While it's unlikely, it might have aborted already but didn't refresh yet.

Comment: Yes, I refresh it every day - days are changing, still no error, no any additional message. Do you know if there is a way to check if GEE script is running or stuck?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to check the progress. You might want to try exporting a much smaller extent as a test if it theoretically works.

Comment: Yes, it worked - I exported Europe before. Also previously it used to work for ~2 days only. Now I changed some points in the script and it's already 11 days now.
Also it slows down a lot other extractions that I want to do (script that used to run for 40 min ran for 1 day now, so I decided to wait).